# Convert .mat to .csv octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, octave

I'm trying to write an octave program that will convert a .mat file to a .csv file. The .mat file has a matrix X and a column vector y. X is populated with 0s and 1s and y is populated with labels from 1 to 10. I want to take y and put it in front of X and write it as a .csv file.

Here is a code snippet of my first approach:

```
load(filename, "X", "y");
z = [y X];

basename = split{1};
csvname = strcat(basename, ".csv");

csvwrite(csvname, z);
```

The resulting file contains lots of really small decimal numbers, e.g. 8.560596795891285e-06,1.940359477121703e-06, etc...

My second approach was to loop through and manually write the values out to the .csv file:

```
load(filename, "X", "y");
z = [y X];

basename = split{1};
csvname = strcat(basename, ".csv");
csvfile = fopen(csvname, "w");

numrows = size(z, 1);
numcols = size(z, 2);

for i = 1:numrows
  for j = 1:numcols
    fprintf(csvfile, "%d", z(i, j));
    if j == numcols
      fprintf(csvfile, "\n");
    else
      fprintf(csvfile, ",");
    end
  end
end

fclose(csvfile);
```

That gave me a correct result, but took a really long time.

Can someone tell me either how to use csvwrite in a way that will write the correct values, or how to more efficiently manually create the .csv file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if `y` is of type `char`, your `X` vector gets converted to char, too. Since your labels are nothing else but numbers, you can simply convert them to numbers and save the data using `csvwrite`:

```
csvwrite('data.txt', [str2num(y) X]);
```

**Edit** Also, in the loop you save the numbers using integer conversion `%d`, while `csvwrite` writes doubles if your data is of type `double`. If the zeros are not exactly zeros, `csvwrite` will write them with scientific notation, while your loop will round them. Hence the different behavior.

Comment: I tried using str2num on vector y, but got an error: Invalid call to str2num...

Then I used isnumeric to check both X and y to verify that both of these contain only numbers. Both returned 1.

Comment: @gpian well, then what you save is your data. Type `X` in the command window and look at the results. And type `whos` to see the type of `y` and `X`.

Comment: X and y both have type double, which I didn't expect, but should be ok. So perhaps there is some floating point rounding error?

Comment: @gpian most likely your zeros are not zeros. Print one such entry on the screen, like X(1,2). One that should be 0. Or type `num2str(X,’%.10f’)`.

Comment: @gpian You round doubles in your loop by casting them to ints. `csvwrite` does not do that. Thats why you get different results.

Comment: I see, so when i do fprintf(csvfile, "%d", z(i,j)) that will round.

Answer (score 3):

Just a heads up your code isn't optimized for Matab / octave. Switch the for i and for j lines around.

Octave is in column major order so its not cache efficient to do what your doing. It will speed up the overall loop by making the change to probably an acceptable time